# Forbid access to website through IP server

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

I am hosting my website on my Debian server. My website is accessible by is domain name https://www.domainname.fr

But nothing prevents users to access the website by the IP of the server /myhostname, so http://serveripadress/domainname/

I put a

```
Options All -Indexes
```

in the .htaccess to Forbidden the access to the website repositories, but I don't want the users navigates on the site by the http://serveripadress/domainname/ url...

I need to automatically redirect people from http://serveripadress/domainname/ to the real domain name https://www.domainname.fr

How can I do that ? Is there other kind of access protection to put on the .htaccess ?

Here is my current .htaccess content:

```
#FallbackResource /index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Désactiver l'exploration des répertoires web
Options All -Indexes
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if hostname in current request is not www.domainname.fr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domainname\.fr$ [NC]
# then redirect
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domainname.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but my .htaccess is not empty (I edit my post), so how can I adapte it ?

Comment: Insert my suggested rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line. As per my edited answer.